# "Exception reading response" error trying to send mail in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, socketexception

Here is a little code to send email from java.

```
public static void sendMail(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.domain.tld");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("sender@domain.tdl", "pwd");
        }
      });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@domain.tdl"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("receiver@yahoo.fr"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setContent("This is a test <b>HOWTO<b>", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But running it I have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at Test.main(Test.java:112)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2445)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2307)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2340)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1808)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1285)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Test.main(Test.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:104)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2425)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't understand the reason of the error because this code worked for me in the past.
Here is the jars I'm using:

- dsn-1.6.0
- gimap-1.6.0
- imap-1.6.0
- javax.mail-1.6.0
- javax.mail-api-1.6.0
- logging-mailhandler-1.6.0
- mailapi-1.6.0
- pop3-1.6.0
- smtp-1.6.0

After modification asked by @Bill, here is the new error I have

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.hereka.org, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at Test.main(Test.java:134)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.hereka.org, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2196)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:726)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:252)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at Test.main(Test.java:130)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:619)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:393)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
    ... 7 more
```

But if I remove the ssl property this is the new error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at Test.main(Test.java:134)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2445)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2307)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2340)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1808)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1285)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at Test.main(Test.java:130)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:104)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2425)
    ... 7 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the jar but more a SMTP server error. 
you could try using

```
telnet mail.domain.tld
```

and try connecting to the host. I suggest you include a port like

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "portnumber");
```

you can try the standard port 25 (unsecure) or 587 (secure) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Guru I tried telnet on port 25 and the conection is done even if I have the message on the console "we do not authorize the use of this systeme to transport unsolicited and/or bulk e-mail".

Comment: On the code I also added like you suggested  `props.put("mail.smtp.port", "portnumber");` now I have the error  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.  (Name)
550-[41.244.226.223]:63273 is not permitted to relay through this server
550 without authentication.`

Comment: If it still fails, turn on [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and add the debug output to your original post above.